# SSRS Query paging

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am creating a report from a very large table. I created a very simple report that simply has one table in it. The table does seem to allow paging but every page load takes so long that it seems as if it was pulling the entire table and then paging locally.

I thought I might have to add the paging to the query myself but this doesn't work because the page variables can only be used in the header or footer

```
="SELECT * FROM MyTable OFFSET " & =Globals!PageNumber & " * 20 LIMIT 20"
```

I haven't used SSRS before so I'm not sure if there is something really obvious that I am missing.

Any help with how to do this properly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using any pagination related expressions, SSRS must retrieve all of the data before it display the first page.

For example, if you are trying to do "Page 1 of X" in the footer, SSRS must figure out how many pages exists (by retrieving and pre-rendering all pages) before it can display page 1.

Also, if you don't need all of the columns, don't use Select *.  That will force SSRS to load every column into its cache even if they are not all used.  You can cut down on the data retrieval execution time.

Finally, if you have access to the SSRS reporting database, you can take a look at the execution statistics for your report to see where the performance problem is happening.  [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159110.aspx](http://Report%20Server%20Execution%20Logs)

Comment: Thanks! Eventually I realized SSRS was too much of a pain for what I needed to do and rolled my own solution. Had a few other requirements that were going to be almost impossible to meet with it.

Answer (score 2):

The Global `PageNumber` in SSRS is generated **after** the report is rendered. That's why you can't use it in the query.

It's unclear exactly what you mean by paging. SSRS automatically creates pages for the report once the table goes over the page size. If you wanted to just query a small chunk of the table and then click a button to get the next chunk, there's nothing like that readily available.

However, you could use the `ROW_NUMBER` function in your query and filter that to a particular range in the report. But you have to specify the value of the parameters/filters before you run the report because it uses those to process the dataset and then goes on to render the report.

Answer (score 0):

Set `KeepTogether` to `False` in your Tablix Control to Enable Paging:
        [image: SSRS - Set KeepTogether to False to Enable Paging]

Without this it would load EVERYTHING into the 1st Page, then the 2nd Page would be Blank.

Nowhere online could I find a way to do this.
I eventually stumbled upon this setting while digging through the properties of another Report
that didn't have this issue; and (through trial-and-error) figured out it enabled the paging.

Warning:
You don't *have* to implement your own custom Paging Query Logic.
However, if it was loading a ton of Records, then it may beat up your Database,
      then flood your network bandwidth; ultimately before timing out.
The User should ***never*** be allowed to Suck Down your entire Database through a Report!

Missing Feature:
It would be nice if SSRS had a Max-Row Feature were you could then Update your Query to Return `TOP 10001` and if your Max-Row was set to 10,000 (with a customizable message), then it could say,
   "*Your Request Exceeds 10,000 Records.  Contact blah-blah-blah to Request an Oversized Data Export.*"
Otherwise your Power-Users will go Power-Hungry with data - and you can't blame them for wanting more.
You don't want to give them a bad experience waiting minutes just to see a blank screen; while you blow money chewing through CPU Clock Cycles and Bandwidth (especially if you're hosting in a metered cloud).

This is why I prefer to roll my own Reporting in Asp.net (and avoid SSRS altogether).
Then I may easily control the Paging and ONLY return from the database what I need
using T-SQL's `OFFSET` & `FETCH` Clause